# What is the difference between CAPM.alpha and CAPM.jensenAlpha

Tags: r, regression, xts, performanceanalytics

What is the difference between the two functions from the `PerformanceAnalytics` package `CAPM.alpha` and `CAPM.jensenAlpha`?

If I set `Ra` and `Rb` and no `Rf=0`, it gives me two different values for my return xts objects. (`Ra` being the excess returns of my portfolio and `Rb` the excess returns of the benchmark, thus no `Rf`)

It gives me an output:

```
> CAPM.jensenAlpha(portfolio,benchmark)
[1] 0.05676789

>CAPM.alpha(portfolio,benchmark)
[1] 0.006135824
```

My returns are monthly excess returns. Moreover, `CAPM.alpha` gives exactly the intercept in a regression of these monthly excess returns. What is then the value for `CAPM.jensenAlpha`? I first thought it could maybe be the annualized alpha, but calculating arithmetically *12 or geometrically (1+alpha)^12-1 doesnt do the trick...

Comment: [jensens Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_alpha)

Comment: I know the difference, but with my data it should give me the same results....